# print to user selected tray in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to print the word document into user selected tray of the printer.

I am working on **VSTO** and developing the new ribbon in ms Word 2010 which includes the printing option as-well. I have managed to read the available trays for the selected printer and also user can select the specific tray.

But the point where I am confused is when I am printing, how should I specify that selected tray?

I am working on vb.net.

Comment: This is in an ASP.NET web application??

Comment: thanks for your message. Nop it is vb.net, but the reason to tag asp.net is that if any could give me some clue even through with asp.net that will be help full as well. because basically i am loosing the concept i got every thing in the fromt of me just need to assign the select try to the pinter ... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the PrinterSettings.PaperSources collection to iterate and determine which tray to use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.papersources

And to iterate, you can use this snippet as basis and expand as necessary:

```
PrintDocument printDoc1 = new PrintDocument();
for (int i = 0; i < printDoc1.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Count; i++)
{
}
```

And to select a specific tray to use, set the  `PageSettings.PaperSource` property.

Comment: Thanks for your help. one more small query. i am using printdoc1 as new printdocument but when i am printing printdoc1.print().. its prints the blank page ......